# removing childviewcontroller disables gestures in parentviewcontroller when the parentviewcontroller is re-presented

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

in iOS when I add a childviewcontroller, then remove it - all gestures that overlap have been disabled.

For example the parentviewcontroller has a 'longtap' gesture, and the childviewcontroller has a 'longtap' gesture.

the parent views longtap gesture works.

then i do addchildviewcontroller and that VCs longtap gesture works.

then i call removeFromParentViewController

and the original viewcontroller's view which used to respond to longtap gestures has had its gesture disabled.

(I could cycle through all the gestures and 'renable' them again - my question is why is the longtap gesture getting disabled when i add, and then remove a childviewcontroller - I'm doing everything standard, ie.

```
[_parentVC                 addChildViewController:alertVC];
[_parentVC                 willMoveToParentViewController:alertVC];
[_parentVC.view addSubview:alertVC.view];
```

then

```
 [alertVC.view removeFromSuperview];
 [alertVC removeFromParentViewController];
 [alertVC willMoveToParentViewController:_parentVC];
```

Comment: where you are defining your gestures??

Comment: Each viewcontroller has its own nib with a UILongPressGestureRecognizer, and each viewcontroller's .h file has an IBAction connected to their gesture. The AlertViewController's signature is -(IBAction) handleLongPressToCloseAlertView:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) recognizer; and the parent view controller's signature is: - (IBAction)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*) recognizer;

Answer (score 0):

Wow.
A lot of code here.
Looks like the gesture was manually disabled after the event took place. So the gesture being disabled had nothing to do with adding childviewcontrollers.